# Activity on back pressed handle

Tags: android, android-activity, onbackpressed

> Activity launcher

I have three activities like Activity A - Activity B - Activity C . Activity launch through intent. When Activity C is  launched and I click back button to get  activity A with out handle back pressed. How can I get this?

Comment: Ask clear question for further research.

Comment: Clear your question by mean of _and I click back button to get activity A with out handle back pressed_

Answer (score 0):

When you are launching Activity C from B then after `startActivity()` method call finish() in Activity-B. It will remove Activity-B from activity-stack.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in Activity C and you want to go back to Activity A without going to Activity B you should use flags.

```
Intent startActivityA = new Intent(ActivityC.this,ActivityA.class);
startActivityA.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(startActivityA);
```

Answer (score -1):

while calling activity C from activity B, you can call finish() method after calling intent. see the syntax below.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    Intent intent=new Intent(B.this,C.Class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```